# Contour plot projection not showing properly in matplotlib 3d plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-3d, random-walk

I was trying to plot the contour plot of the walker's position of a random walker moving in a 3d space on the xy, xz, and yz plane. I am getting a proper contour plot while plotting it in the xy plane but for the xz and yz it's not coming properly, it is showing some weired sort of distribution about the zeroline. Kindly suggest me some solutions on how to deal with this problem.

I am plotting this in Jupyter Notebook(Python). The code snippet along with the plot I have got, is attached below. Please provide a plot if the problem is fixed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

stepsize = 0.5
num_steps = 250
num_trials = 10**3

final_path = []

for _ in range(num_trials+1):
    pos = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
    for _ in range(num_steps+1):
        pos= pos+  np.random.normal(0,0.5,3)
    final_path.append(list(pos))

final_path = np.array(final_path)

x = final_path[:,0]
y = final_path[:,1]
z = final_path[:,2]

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,12)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d', computed_zorder = False)
ax.scatter(x,y,z, c = 'blue', s = 40, zorder = 2)
# ax.plot(x, y, z, 'k-',  linewidth=0.5, zorder = 2)

ax.scatter(x,y, zs = min(z), zdir = 'z', color = 'black',s = 8, zorder = 1)
ax.scatter(x,z, zs = max(y), zdir = 'y', color = 'black',s = 8, zorder = 1)
ax.scatter(y,z, zs = min(x), zdir = 'x', color = 'black',s = 8, zorder = 1)

counts_xy, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=25)
x_grid_xy, y_grid_xy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 25), np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 25))

counts_xz, xedges, zedges = np.histogram2d(x, z, bins=25)
x_grid_xz, z_grid_xz = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 25), np.linspace(min(z), max(z), 25))

counts_yz, yedges, zedges = np.histogram2d(y, z, bins=25)
y_grid_yz, z_grid_yz = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 25), np.linspace(min(z), max(z), 25))

ax.contourf(x_grid_xy, y_grid_xy, counts_xy.T, zdir='z', offset=min(z), levels = 25, cmap='Reds', zorder=0)
ax.contourf(x_grid_xz, z_grid_xz, counts_xz.T, zdir='y', offset=max(y), levels = 25, cmap='Greens', zorder=0)
ax.contourf(y_grid_yz, z_grid_yz, counts_yz.T, zdir='x', offset=min(x), levels = 25, cmap='Blues', zorder=0)

ax.set_xlim(min(x),max(x))
ax.set_ylim(min(y),max(y))
ax.set_zlim(min(z),max(z))
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('Walker\'s Position in 3D Space')

plt.show()
```

[Plotting the Position of a Random walker after 10^3 trials along with the contour projection of the position on the xy, xz and yz planes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp7sJ.png)

I tried to find a solution in ChatGPT but it also didn't work. I tried with the following lines of codes for the contour plot but in this case too, the contour in the xy-plane came properly and those in the xz and yz planes came as shown in the figure.

```
counts_xy, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=25)
x_grid_xy, y_grid_xy = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], yedges[:-1])

counts_xz, xedges, zedges = np.histogram2d(x, z, bins=25)
x_grid_xz, z_grid_xz = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], zedges[:-1])

counts_yz, yedges, zedges = np.histogram2d(y, z, bins=25)
y_grid_yz, z_grid_yz = np.meshgrid(yedges[:-1], zedges[:-1])

ax.contourf(x_grid_xy, y_grid_xy, counts_xy.T, zdir='z', offset=min(z), levels=50, cmap='Reds', zorder=0)
ax.contourf(x_grid_xz, z_grid_xz, counts_xz.T, zdir='y', offset=max(y), levels=50, cmap='Greens', zorder=0)
ax.contourf(y_grid_yz, z_grid_yz, counts_yz.T, zdir='x', offset=min(x), levels=50, cmap='Blues', zorder=0)
```